# Running shell command from python script with \n

Tags: python, docker, shell, subprocess, jupyter

I am trying to run the shell command

```
echo -e 'FROM busybox\nRUN echo "hello world"' | docker build -t myimage:latest -
```

from jupyter notebook using subprocesses

I have tried the code

```
p = subprocess.Popen('''echo -e 'FROM busybox\nRUN echo "hello world"' | docker build -t myimage:latest - ''', shell=True)
p.communicate()
```

and some iterations with run() or call(), but everytime the output is

> -e 'FROM busybox

It seems that the new line character \n causes the problem. Any ideas to solve the problem?

Comment: Create sh script file, put all your lines there and run it from python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\n` gets parsed by Python into a literal newline. You can avoid that by using a raw string instead,

```py
p = subprocess.run(
    r'''echo -e 'FROM busybox\nRUN echo "hello world"' | docker build -t myimage:latest - ''',
    shell=True, check=True)
```

but I would recommend running a single process and passing in the output from Python; this also [avoids a shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess), which is generally desirable.

```py
p = subprocess.run(['docker', 'build', '-t', 'myimage:latest', '-'],
    input='FROM busybox\nRUN echo "hello world"',
    text=True, check=True)
```

Notice also how we prefer `subprocess.run()` over the more primitive `subprocess.Popen()`; as suggested in the documentation, you want to avoid this low-level function whenever you can. With `check=True` we also take care to propagate any subprocess errors up to the Python parent process.

As an aside, `printf` is both more versatile and more portable than `echo -e`; I would generally recommend you to avoid `echo -e` altogether.

This [ideone demo with `nl` instead of `docker build`](https://ideone.com/MF4KdF) demonstrates the variations, and coincidentally proves why you want to avoid `echo -e` even if your login shell is e.g. Bash (in which case you'd think it should be supported; but `subprocess` doesn't use your login shell).

Comment: You could add that to get a raw string one must add `r` in front of that string as such: `r'string goes here'` (although that is basic doc info and should be easily found)

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. The second solution with run() executed successfully with the addition of encode() to the "input", because a byte-like object is required, not a string. The problem with the raw string is that \n is passed as a literal to echo and it's not interpreted as new line.

Comment: Gotcha, sorry about that, and thanks for the edit!